# Angular can't insert a specific DOM ？

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm coding a Chrome Extension with Angular, when i write `content_scripts` i find Angular can't insert a specific DOM.

If i use React:

```js
// foo is id in page I will use content script 
const specificDOM = document.getElementById('foo');

class Component extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

ReactDOM.render(Component, specificDOM)
```

Does Angular have a similar method ？

Comment: You can do with Javascript only within the Angular component. The best place would be `  ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: @MaihanNijat emm..  I'm talking about how to use angular partially on a page